# In walk navigation, is there a way to prevent camera from walking through objects?

Tags: camera, constraints, collision, navigation

I am recording the camera walk navigation movement (Like a gameplay) and I don't want it to pass through walls and other objects. Is there a way to do that in blender? I also had the idea of adding collision to the camera but I did not find the option available for the camera.

Comment: There are various Object Constraint properties that you can add to the camera (Limit Location, Distance, etc.) but not collision as far as I'm aware. Although I've never used it, I'd guess that the version of Blender with the game engine in it (search for UPBGE) would be more likely to have that option in it.